# Android classes in libgdx projects

Tags: java, android, class, libgdx

I can't figure out how to use android classes (for example: classes that give you access to the folders from your phone) in a libgdx project. I'm using Netbeans and I searched for a solution to my problem, but none helped me. Please give me an explanation  on how to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: From the official documentation: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: Please, do not use NetBeans for android development... Eclipse and Android studio are made for this.